# Navigation Bar Items evenly spread

Tags: html, css

I am very new to html and css and I am currently struggling with my nav bar. The items should all take up the same amount of space (like in this picture [screenshot of my screendesign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7Hoj.jpg)). How do I achieve the position of my nav-bar elements? Also why is my font-size suddenly so small even though I used the same font size as in my screendesign?

```css
body, html {
    width: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 2400px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
  
body{
    font-family: Baskerville, Helvetica, serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    color: #A5A58D;
    background-image: url(file:///Users/alinasprenger/Documents/FH%20St.%20Po%CC%88lten/Interaktive%20Medien/Images/Pottery%20Website%20Background%20Blurred-1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
      
.header1{
    height: 50px;
    padding: 50px 0 5px 0;
    font-size: 41px;
    text-transform:   uppercase;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after{
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.cf:after{
  clear:both;
}

.cf{
  zoom:1;
}

nav{
  background: #B7B7A4;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 42px;
}

ul, li{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;

}

ul{
  background: #B7B7A4;
  height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
}

li a{
  display: block;
  line-height: 42px;
  padding: 0 1em;
  color: #FFF1E6;
}

li a:hover{
  background: #AEAE98;
  height: 42px;
  position: relative;
}

.current, a:hover.current{
  background: #909072;
  color: #FFF1E6;
  position: relative;
  height: 42px;
}

.header2{
    display: flex;
    height: 90px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20% 0 0 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #A5A58D;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20%;
}

.header3{
    font-size: 41px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 485px;
    height: 445px;
    background-color: #A5A58D;
    color: #EDDCD2;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 2em;
    margin-left: 5em;
    text-align: center;
    top: 1544px;
    left: 22%;
}
  
.textparagraphen1{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 485px;
    height: 445px;
    background-color: #A5A58D;
    color: #EDDCD2;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 15px;
    top: 239px;
    left: 22%;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 23px;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #EDDCD2;
}


.textparagraphen2{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 485px;
    height: 445px;
    background-color: #A5A58D;
    color: #EDDCD2;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
    top: 999px;
    left: 53%;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 23px;
}

.textparagraphen3{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 485px;
    height: 445px;
    background-color: #A5A58D;
    color: #EDDCD2;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 15px;
        top: 1544px;
        left: 22%;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 23px;
    }

    .textparagraphen4{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column; 
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 68.4%;
        height: 453px;
        background-color: #A5A58D;
        color: #EDDCD2;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: 0 15% 0 15%;
        top: 255px;
        position: absolute;
        line-height: 23px;
    }

 

    .linksammlung{
        
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: #EDDCD2;
        font-size: 22px;
        text-transform:   uppercase;
        font-weight: bold;
    }


    .abbildung1{
        position: absolute;
        left: 53%;
        top: 239px;
    }
      
    .abbildung2{
        position: absolute;
        left: 10%;
        top: 784px;
    }

    .abbildung3{
        position: absolute;
        left: 53%;
        top: 1544px;
    }

    .abbildung5{
        position: absolute;
        left: 15%;
        top: 1664px;
    }

    .abbildung6{
        position: absolute;
        left: 52.6%;
        top: 1664px;
    }

    .tutorialvideo{
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 808px;
}

.footerContainer {
    top: 2322px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
  
.footer{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #A5A58D;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #A5A58D;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
  
.footer2{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #A5A58D;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en"> 


<head>
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="WS 2020 Screendesign Unterseiten.css">

<title> ALINA'S POTTERY </title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header1"> Alina's Pottery </div>
  
  <nav class="cf">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html" title="Home" class="category">Home</a></li>
    <li class="current"><a href="pottery.html" title="Pottery" class="category">Pottery</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="general.html" title="General" class="subCategory">General</a></li>
        <li><a href="handbuilding.html" title="Hand-Building" class="subCategory">Hand-Building</a></li>
        <li><a href="potterywheel.html" title="Pottery Wheel" class="subCategory">Pottery Wheel</a></li>
        <li><a href="materials.html" title="Materials" class="subCategory">Materials</a></li>
        <li><a href="temperatures.html" title="Temperatures" class="subCategory">Temperatures</a></li>
    </ul>   
    </li>

    <li><a href="tutorials.html" title="Tutorials" class="category">Tutorials</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="viewall.html" title="View All" class="subCategory">View All</a></li>
            <li><a href="getstarted.html" title="Get Started" class="subCategory">Get Started</a></li>
            <li><a href="plates.html" title="Plates" class="subCategory">Plates</a></li>
            <li><a href="mugs.html" title="Mugs" class="subCategory">Mugs</a></li>
            <li><a href="bowls.html" title="Bowls" class="subCategory">Bowls</a></li>
        </ul>   
        </li>
    <li><a href="shop.html" title="Shop" class="category">Shop</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section class="textparagraphen1">
<div class="text2"> 
    Pottery is the process</br>
    and the products of forming objects</br>
    of desired shape with clay</br>
    and other ceramic materials,</br> 
    which are fired at high temperatures </br>
    (600-1600°C) to give them a hard,</br>
    durable form. </br>
    Major types include earthenware,</br>
    stoneware and porcelain. </br>
</br>
</br>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pottery">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pottery</a>
</div>

</section>

<section class="textparagraphen2">
    <div class="text4">
        The most common forms of pottery </br>
        are hand-building and</br>
        pottery on a wheel.</br>
        I mainly do hand-building</br>
        with stoneware because</br>
        I love the unique look every</br>
        single piece gets.</br>
        After firing, I glaze my work</br>
        and then fire it again.</br>
        That way, you can even wash</br>
        your ceramics in the dish-washer!</br>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="textparagraphen3">
    <div class="text5">
        The result is incredibly individual</br>
        tableware that will make everybody</br>
        want to know where you got it from.</br>

        The process is not only easy,</br>
        but also so much fun!</br>
        </br>

        #potterylove
    </div>

</section>



<div class="abbildung1">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5567000/pexels-photo-5567000.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-anastasia-shuraeva-5567000.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="Pottery Wheel" width="712px" height="660px">
</div>

<div class="abbildung2">
    <img src="" alt="Hand Building" width="712px" height="660px">
</div>


<div class="abbildung3">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5567010/pexels-photo-5567010.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-anastasia-shuraeva-5567010.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="Pottery Pieces" width="712px" height="660px">
</div>



<div class="footerContainer">
    <a href="aboutme.html" title="About Me" class="footer">About Me</a>
    <a href="socials.html" title="Socials" class="footer"> Socials</a>
    <a href="imprint.html" title="Imprint" class="footer2">Imprint</a> 
</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added `display: flex` into your ul element, with that, all the elements inside of this ul, will occupy the same space.
About the font size beign small, you are setting in the body `font-size: 20px`, every element that is inside your body, will inheritance that size, also, in your `nav` element, again you're setting `20px`, if you want bigger font size, try using a different value other than 20px

Hope it works for you!

```css
body, html {
    width: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 2400px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
  
body{
    font-family: Baskerville, Helvetica, serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    color: #A5A58D;
    background-image: url(file:///Users/alinasprenger/Documents/FH%20St.%20Po%CC%88lten/Interaktive%20Medien/Images/Pottery%20Website%20Background%20Blurred-1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
      
.header1{
    height: 50px;
    padding: 50px 0 5px 0;
    font-size: 41px;
    text-transform:   uppercase;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after{
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.cf:after{
  clear:both;
}

.cf{
  zoom:1;
}

nav{
  background: #B7B7A4;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 42px;
}

ul, li{
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;

}

ul{
  background: #B7B7A4;
  height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
}

li a{
  display: block;
  line-height: 42px;
  padding: 0 1em;
  color: #FFF1E6;
}

li a:hover{
  background: #AEAE98;
  height: 42px;
  position: relative;
}

.current, a:hover.current{
  background: #909072;
  color: #FFF1E6;
  position: relative;
  height: 42px;
}

.header2{
    display: flex;
    height: 90px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20% 0 0 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #A5A58D;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20%;
}

.header3{
    font-size: 41px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 485px;
    height: 445px;
    background-color: #A5A58D;
    color: #EDDCD2;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 2em;
    margin-left: 5em;
    text-align: center;
    top: 1544px;
    left: 22%;
}
  
.textparagraphen1{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 485px;
    height: 445px;
    background-color: #A5A58D;
    color: #EDDCD2;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 15px;
    top: 239px;
    left: 22%;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 23px;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #EDDCD2;
}


.textparagraphen2{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 485px;
    height: 445px;
    background-color: #A5A58D;
    color: #EDDCD2;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
    top: 999px;
    left: 53%;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 23px;
}

.textparagraphen3{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 485px;
    height: 445px;
    background-color: #A5A58D;
    color: #EDDCD2;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 15px;
        top: 1544px;
        left: 22%;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 23px;
    }

    .textparagraphen4{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column; 
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 68.4%;
        height: 453px;
        background-color: #A5A58D;
        color: #EDDCD2;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: 0 15% 0 15%;
        top: 255px;
        position: absolute;
        line-height: 23px;
    }

 

    .linksammlung{
        
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: #EDDCD2;
        font-size: 22px;
        text-transform:   uppercase;
        font-weight: bold;
    }


    .abbildung1{
        position: absolute;
        left: 53%;
        top: 239px;
    }
      
    .abbildung2{
        position: absolute;
        left: 10%;
        top: 784px;
    }

    .abbildung3{
        position: absolute;
        left: 53%;
        top: 1544px;
    }

    .abbildung5{
        position: absolute;
        left: 15%;
        top: 1664px;
    }

    .abbildung6{
        position: absolute;
        left: 52.6%;
        top: 1664px;
    }

    .tutorialvideo{
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 808px;
}

.footerContainer {
    top: 2322px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
  
.footer{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #A5A58D;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #A5A58D;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
  
.footer2{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #A5A58D;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en"> 


<head>
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="WS 2020 Screendesign Unterseiten.css">

<title> ALINA'S POTTERY </title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header1"> Alina's Pottery </div>
  
  <nav class="cf">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html" title="Home" class="category">Home</a></li>
    <li class="current"><a href="pottery.html" title="Pottery" class="category">Pottery</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="general.html" title="General" class="subCategory">General</a></li>
        <li><a href="handbuilding.html" title="Hand-Building" class="subCategory">Hand-Building</a></li>
        <li><a href="potterywheel.html" title="Pottery Wheel" class="subCategory">Pottery Wheel</a></li>
        <li><a href="materials.html" title="Materials" class="subCategory">Materials</a></li>
        <li><a href="temperatures.html" title="Temperatures" class="subCategory">Temperatures</a></li>
    </ul>   
    </li>

    <li><a href="tutorials.html" title="Tutorials" class="category">Tutorials</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="viewall.html" title="View All" class="subCategory">View All</a></li>
            <li><a href="getstarted.html" title="Get Started" class="subCategory">Get Started</a></li>
            <li><a href="plates.html" title="Plates" class="subCategory">Plates</a></li>
            <li><a href="mugs.html" title="Mugs" class="subCategory">Mugs</a></li>
            <li><a href="bowls.html" title="Bowls" class="subCategory">Bowls</a></li>
        </ul>   
        </li>
    <li><a href="shop.html" title="Shop" class="category">Shop</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section class="textparagraphen1">
<div class="text2"> 
    Pottery is the process</br>
    and the products of forming objects</br>
    of desired shape with clay</br>
    and other ceramic materials,</br> 
    which are fired at high temperatures </br>
    (600-1600°C) to give them a hard,</br>
    durable form. </br>
    Major types include earthenware,</br>
    stoneware and porcelain. </br>
</br>
</br>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pottery">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pottery</a>
</div>

</section>

<section class="textparagraphen2">
    <div class="text4">
        The most common forms of pottery </br>
        are hand-building and</br>
        pottery on a wheel.</br>
        I mainly do hand-building</br>
        with stoneware because</br>
        I love the unique look every</br>
        single piece gets.</br>
        After firing, I glaze my work</br>
        and then fire it again.</br>
        That way, you can even wash</br>
        your ceramics in the dish-washer!</br>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="textparagraphen3">
    <div class="text5">
        The result is incredibly individual</br>
        tableware that will make everybody</br>
        want to know where you got it from.</br>

        The process is not only easy,</br>
        but also so much fun!</br>
        </br>

        #potterylove
    </div>

</section>



<div class="abbildung1">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5567000/pexels-photo-5567000.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-anastasia-shuraeva-5567000.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="Pottery Wheel" width="712px" height="660px">
</div>

<div class="abbildung2">
    <img src="" alt="Hand Building" width="712px" height="660px">
</div>


<div class="abbildung3">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5567010/pexels-photo-5567010.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-anastasia-shuraeva-5567010.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="Pottery Pieces" width="712px" height="660px">
</div>



<div class="footerContainer">
    <a href="aboutme.html" title="About Me" class="footer">About Me</a>
    <a href="socials.html" title="Socials" class="footer"> Socials</a>
    <a href="imprint.html" title="Imprint" class="footer2">Imprint</a> 
</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```